# Scraping td elements in a table in HTML

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have to get the Text from the `td` elements from a table in html which looks like this:

```
<table  id="gvrslt" >
    <tbody><tr style="font-size:10pt;">
        <th scope="col">Sem</th><th scope="col" style="font-size:X-Small;">Total Obtained Marks</th><th scope="col" style="font-size:X-Small;">Max Total Marks</th><th scope="col">Result</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">VI</td>
        <td align="center">458</td>
        <td align="center">550</td>
        <td align="center">PASSED</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I want to grab the `458` from the table which has more such `td` elements.The problem is that before getting to the Results' page and getting the above HTML, I have to enter some credentials and then a Result page is shown with **Right click disabled**. Now I can get the source of the Results' page via `driver.page_source` but when I try to find the `table` elements via webdriver, it searches the page where I entered the credentials and not the actual results' page. Is there a way to search the `driver.page_source` for `table` and `td` elements

Here is my code:

```
html=driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table=soup.find_all('table',id='gvrslt')

print(table)
```

Comment: Your login is probably not successful

Comment: @PadraicCunningham if it wasn't, I wouldn't be looking at my result

Comment: so you see  the table in driver.page_source?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the text directly you can use a css locator to get to the 2nd `td` directly instead of using the table.

```
table[id='gvrslt'] td:nth-of-type(2)
```

`nth-of-type` gets you the 2nd `td` element

Answer (score 0):

Try using Xpath in this case:

```
//table[@id='gvrslt']//td[index]
```

with your **index** of td

Comment: it searches the page where I enter credentials and not the results' page.

Comment: Check this link, it may help you in working with page_source
http://seleniumwebdrivertrainings.com/how-to-get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with selenium using python. What you try is find the value using xpath.

In C# below is the code. See if it can hep you in any way possible.

```
IWebElement tdCell = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"));
string valueOfTd = tdCell.Text;
```

Comment: The problem is that webdriver searches for the page where I enter the credentials and not the actual results' page where right click is disabled.

Comment: If your actual results is in different tab or window, then you have to switch the window. Else wait for the page load, and then try again.

Comment: actual results open in the same window and then I grab the source using `driver.page_source` which has results embedded in a table. How should I search this source for table contents?

Comment: Sorry i don't know about `driver.page_source` and `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)`, generally i directly use `driver.FindElement()` to locate elements.